# What features makes a good groin protector?

Tags: equipment, krav-maga, protective-equipment

I previously used a groin protector in kickboxing but that still hurt when you take a kick.

Most groin protectors will not work in Krav Maga, which is very heavy groin-kick oriented. What makes a good groin protector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been training in (and recently teaching) Krav Maga for a while, and groin kicks are a regular occurrence. From my experience, it really doesn't matter all that much which cup you use, as long as you check it regularly, it shouldn't break spontaneously. Cups will usually crack first. Even if you wear a cup, it's still gonna hurt, you just have to get used to it. The difference is whether or not there is any real damage being done.

There are a few things to make sure of to eliminate the risk of injury:

1. Make sure it fits tightly:

   - Personally, I prefer [Jock Straps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jockstrap) over [Compression Shorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_shorts). Jock Straps tend to [hold the cup in place better](http://www.kravmaga.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-5108.html), while compression shorts tend to be loose. The one time I tried using Compression Shorts instead, I ended up getting kneed, the cup shifted, and actually made it worse...
2. Make sure you check it regularly:

   - If you notice any cracks in it, replace it! In Krav Maga, you *will* get kicked in the groin! *A lot!* My instructor has a collection of broken cups in his office (yes... he broke them all himself...) The last thing you want is for one to fail when you need it.

Besides that, just make sure that whatever you buy has good reviews. And get used to the idea of getting kicked *hard* in the groin. It's gonna happen a lot, but as long as you are wearing proper groin protection, and you check it regularly, it shouldn't do any real damage.

Answer (score 3):

Muay Thai steel cups are the only way to go. Anything else has the potential (small, but still potential) of breaking when hit hard enough, and worst case scenario you get your foreskin ripped along with other such unpleasantness. They're also almost always too narrow, so it's easy to get one of your testicles caught between the cup and your thigh, which is actually more painful than just being hit.

If you don't like the 'g-string' aspect of Thai cups, Ring to Cage makes a supporter that goes with a steel cup that should also work fine (I haven't tried it, I wear my cup when I expect the intensity to be high so I don't notice any minor discomfort, so the traditional design doesn't bother me).

Answer (score 2):

I use Shock Jock compression shorts with the added cup. How would it handle a full force knee to the groin? No idea, just as I have no idea how well my mouth guard would handle a full force elbow to my chin. It does handle the level of force used in my training, and I have caught some pretty good shots.

Comment: Thanks. What are you training ?

Comment: Okinawan Kenpo and some RBSD.

Answer (score 2):

Ephraim has it 100% correct. Number one rule is to keep your balls inside the cup and the cup tight to your groin.

I typically wear boxer brief underwear with a pouch and a 3” athletic supporter with knit pouch (traditional jockstrap) and shorts on top. I use hard contoured athletic cups, often referred to as a ‘banana cup’. Five minutes before Krav Maga class starts, I find a quiet corner, turn my back, and insert the cup between my underwear and jockstrap.  The boxer briefs protect inner legs from cup rash and wick away moisture.

I agree, you should check your cup regularly by slightly squeezing on the sides to check for cracks before wearing the cup. I also recommend cleaning the cup with antibacterial soap in the sink and drying it with a paper towel weekly to eliminate bacterial growth.

My only other added advice is to check and adjust cup as needed in training. If you are doing side kicks, or a lot of high front kicks, your cup can move.  If a MLB baseball player can adjust his cup after every pitch, a Krav Maga student should have the confidence to check their cup 4-6 times in a 90 minute class.

Stay safe